# Python - What takes longer, converting to string or converting to float

Tags: python

Does anyone know if converting a string to float takes longer then converting float to string in general?

I ran a singular scenario using timeit, it seems that over many iterations string to float is faster. But I don't know if this is just because of the one scenario/value I'm testing with.

```
print(timeit.timeit('float("10.2222345")', number=1000000))
print(timeit.timeit('str(10.2222345)', number=1000000))

0.20839183280516668
0.5629733898818098
```

Comment: So the difference is roughly 300 nanoseconds per conversion?  At this point why would this matter?

Comment: @tnknepp I believe the result is in seconds, so 300 ms.

Comment: Yes, but this is 300 ms over 1 million iterations....300E-3 / 1E6 = 300E-9 (300 nanoseconds)

Comment: I'm testing for high iterations because my use case is high iterations, or else I wouldn't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case, timings:

```
%timeit float("10.2222345")
181 ns ± 7.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit str(10.2222345)
590 ns ± 3.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit f'{10.2222345}'  # thx Jaba for pointing this
12 ns ± 0.145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

I strongly believe, the difference comes from memory difference between floats and strings, in most interpreted languages non-asymptotic (your big O notation) performance depends on how much memory needs to be [re]allocated and GC collected. Strings in python not meant to be memory efficient (in first place)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(10.2222345)
24

>>> sys.getsizeof("10.2222345")
59
```

Comment: You can print floats faster if you don't mind getting just the representation of their bits rather than a rounded decimal string with only the significant digits.

Comment: It is also a little noteworthy that `f-strings` in Python3.6+ perform marginally better than `str()`. I ran a `timeit` on `timeit.timeit('str(10.2222345)')` vs `timeit.timeit('f"{10.2222345}"')` and the results were `0.41893691700533964` and `0.41682645901164506` respectively. That’s a difference of `0.002110457993694581` seconds. However this does not change the memory usage of the string afterward.

Comment: Yep, thx for pointing out. f-strings vs `str` – well, function calls is not free :D